# In excel, how to calculate the sum of numbers in a string?

Tags: arrays, excel, string

Now I have a string like "3,15,12,24,3,6,9,15", and I want to know the average of all the numbers in this string, how to realize this in excel or spss?

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: I have tried to use VBA to solve this, but I found that it is too complicated. Now I still do not know.

Answer (score 1):

1. Read the string.
2. Replace the `,` with `+`.
3. Evaluate.

`MsgBox Evaluate(Replace("3,15,12,24,3,6,9,15", ",", "+"))`

---

Or simply parse the string to Array and work with the array:

```
Dim myArr as Variant
myArr = Split("3,15,12,24,3,6,9,15", ",")
```

---

Concerning the comment:
*I have a lot of strings like"3,15,12......", most of them are in one column, how to deal with all the strings at the same time?*
The easiest solution is probably the following:

1. Select the cells;
2. On the Ribbon>Data>Text to Columns;
3. Select Comma as a separator;
4. Work with the new values per cell, using `=SUM()` and `=AVG()`;

[image]

Comment: I suspect that OP want's to use an excel formula for this and not VBA :)

Comment: @Zac - anything is possible.

Comment: Very true! and the combination would probably suffice either or both

Comment: Hi Vityata,thanks for your answer. But I have a lot of strings like"3,15,12......", most of them are in one column, how to deal with all the strings at the same time?